# Filtering the Ajax combobox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit, filtering

I am using Ajax toolkit with a combobox functionality, the items being displayed are around 40,000, so I want to apply a filter on the same, so that a user types an alphabet in the combobox and corresponding entries with starting alphabet "a" will be displayed in the combobox.

Can I have an idea, I am not using Radcombobox, it is a simplest combobox.

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="AppComCombx" runat="server" 
                                CssClass="dropdownpersonal textfont" 
                                onselectedindexchanged="AppComCombx_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"> 
</asp:ComboBox>
```

Comment: You should use `AutoComplete Externder` for that instead of `Combobox`.

Comment: @ yogi:I am bounded to use ajax only.:(

Comment: Yes there is an `AutoComplete Extener` in Ajax Toolkit go here :http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Comment: I am not looking for extender, I want to know If we can implement the same in normal combobox.

Comment: If you really want to achieve that using a list, you can also use a `DropDownList` combined with a `ListSearchExtender`. The good point is that you can also use a "Contains" filter instead of a "StartWith" filter. The bad thing is that the control is a little bit glitched in Chrome and Firefox, but works fine with IE - paradoxically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : `AutoCompleteMode = "SuggestAppend"`

Like this

```
<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server"
     AutoPostBack="False"
     DropDownStyle="DropDownList"
     AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend"
     CaseSensitive="False"
     CssClass=""
     ItemInsertLocation="Append" />
```

For more info go [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx)

Comment: This was doing a bit I wanted, it is showing me the results when I type something in the combobox, but for the whole functionality, I wanted that If I type, A, then only entries starting with the A case should be there in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the `ScriptManager` reference on js file with script below and use `Suggest` or `None` mode for combo

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
    Sys.Extended.UI.ComboBox.prototype._ensureHighlightedIndex = function () {
        // highlight an index according to textbox value
        var textBoxValue = this.get_textBoxControl().value;

        // first, check the current highlighted index
        if (this._highlightedIndex != null && this._highlightedIndex >= 0
            && this._isExactMatch(this._optionListItems[this._highlightedIndex].text, textBoxValue)) {
            return;
        }

        // need to find the correct index
        var firstMatch = -1;
        var ensured = false;
        var children = this.get_optionListControl().childNodes;

        for (var i = 0; i < this._optionListItems.length; i++) {
            var itemText = this._optionListItems[i].text;
            children[i].style.display = this._isPrefixMatch(itemText, textBoxValue) ? "list-item" : "none";

            if (!ensured && this._isExactMatch(itemText, textBoxValue)) {
                this._highlightListItem(i, true);
                ensured = true;
            }
            // if in DropDownList mode, save first match.
            else if (!ensured && firstMatch < 0 && this._highlightSuggestedItem) {
                if (this._isPrefixMatch(itemText, textBoxValue)) {
                    firstMatch = i;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!ensured) {
            this._highlightListItem(firstMatch, true);
        }
    };
});
```

AutoCompleteExtender is better choice in this case as all the way ComboBox will render all items on a page